# MySQL replication and replicating MySQL users

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have a MySQL Main Server and a slave server which replicates the main server.

My question is, the new MySQL users added to the Main Server do not get replicated to the slave server.

How can I make sure that slave server replicates *everything* including new created databases as well as MySQL user accounts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `mysql` table is also replicated. See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-features-userprivs.html) doc for information.